# What is the percentage of ortho to para helium in the Universe?

Tags: helium

Helium is the second most abundant element in the Universe with 24%.
But I could not find any data about what percentage is para to ortho.
In my opinion there will be slightly more para helium because its last energy levels are higher than that of ortho.
If you don't have data you can just comment my guess.

Comment: Related, if not an outright dupe. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/45000/what-is-the-percentage-of-ortho-vs-parahelium-in-the-sun/45009?r=SearchResults&s=1|12.2458#45009

Comment: No answer there.

Comment: @JamesK how might this be a duplicate? Isn't "in the universe" different than "in the Sun"?

Comment: Yes @JamesK exactly, as the conditions in the stars a severe as was answered in that post, I rearranged for space. In 'empty' space there is plenty of helium.